# google maps marker groups and infowindow tabs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've done some research into this but can't seem to find any usable code for what I need to happen on my google map. I have a XML file with database info that is used by google maps to put markers of events and locations on a google map, but some events are on different days/times at the same location and thus get overridden by the next marker at that site.

The method that seemed the best for this was a tabbed info window with the events listed as tabs. Another idea I found was exploding the markers and then being able to select them from there, but the current spider code seems a bit unorganized visually.

Are there any recommendations or links to some java script doing these things? Thanks!

The way that I came up with (but may not know all the code required) is to check, while making the markers, if another marker has the same LatLng and then add a tab to that one instead. I think this would be an if/else statement.

Comment: Is there a way to search all current markers and then add a tab if another marker has the same google.maps.LAtLng?

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to have 2 tables .

Table 1. Location with ID [**(Primary key)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html) & lat/lng etc.

Table 2. Event linked to Location ID with  ID (Foreign key) & events, dates.

This will let you see only 1 marker per location. For tabbed infowindow see [**Google Demo**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Marker clusterer let your define marker clusters client side. But I feel you need a more complex solution like a proximity search or a harvesine formula.

Comment: I'm trying to make this as uncomplicated as possible :) I am having a hard time figuring out how to cycle through current markers to see if one has the same lat lng as my current data. I assume the easiest way is to set up a for loop, but I'm not sure what value of a marker to associate the "i" value with. I thought zIndex maybe, but how would I code that?

Comment: I don't have any problems with that but you need to explain more or post some code. Of course you can find your own algorithm but I think marker cluster is close to your solution because it doesn't use a proximity search or harvesine formula or any complicated solution at all.